# How do I make doxygen hide enum values in documenting each member?

Tags: enums, hide, doxygen

For example, I have source code

```
enum ColorModel
{
     COLOR_MODEL_RGB               = 0,
     COLOR_MODEL_RGBA              = 1,
     COLOR_MODEL_Grayscale         = 2,
     COLOR_MODEL_GrayscaleAlpha    = 3,
     COLOR_MODEL_CMYK              = 4,
};
```

And after generation, in Enumerations section I get:

```
enum    EColorModel { 
    COLOR_MODEL_RGB = 0, COLOR_MODEL_RGBA = 1, COLOR_MODEL_Grayscale = 2, COLOR_MODEL_GrayscaleAlpha = 3, COLOR_MODEL_CMYK = 4 
}
```

How can I hide values to get just

```
enum    EColorModel { 
    COLOR_MODEL_RGB,
    COLOR_MODEL_RGBA,
    COLOR_MODEL_Grayscale,
    COLOR_MODEL_GrayscaleAlpha,
    COLOR_MODEL_CMYK,
}
```

Comment: I hope to get: enum EColorModel { COLOR_MODEL_RGB, COLOR_MODEL_RGBA, COLOR_MODEL_Grayscale, COLOR_MODEL_GrayscaleAlpha, COLOR_MODEL_CMYK}

Answer (score 3):

Set the following in doxygen's configuration file:

```
MAX_INITIALIZER_LINES = 0
```